# mysql/php insert into does nothing and no errors

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've been working on a MySQL database, and now I started to make some basic features for it; like single row deleting, updating and etc... My problem is, that my PHP file is not sending data to the database/table. I checked the variables, and they get trough the form, but no error message is shown except one notice.

My code is:

```
$tablanev = $_POST['tablaNev']; 
$oktazon = $_POST['OktAzon'];
$ehaazon = $_POST['EHA'];
$teljnev = $_POST['TeljesNev'];
$szemelyszam = $_POST['Szemelyazon'];
$anyanyelv = $_POST['Anyanyelv'];
$vegzettseg = $_POST['Vegzettseg'];
$anyanev = $_POST['AnyjaNeve'];
$szulhely = $_POST['SzulHe'];
$szulev = $_POST['SzulEv'];
$allampolg = $_POST['Allampolg'];
$neme = $_POST['Nem'];
$adoaz = $_POST['AdoSz'];
$taj = $_POST['TajSz'];
$bszamla = $_POST['BankSz'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","alma");
mysql_select_db('etr');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablanev(`OktAzonosito`,`EHAazonosito`,`TeljesNev`,`Szemelyazonosito`,`AnyaNyelv`,`VegzettsegSzint`,`AnyjaNeve`,`SzuletesiHely`,`SzuletesiEv`,`Allampolgarsag`,`Neme`,`Adoazonosito`,`TAJszam`,`BankszamlaSzam`) VALUES ('$oktazon','$ehaazon','$teljnev','$szemelyszam','$anyanyelv','$vegzettseg','$anyanev','$szulhely','$szulev','$allampolg','$neme','$taj','$bszamla')");

echo "Az adat sikeresen fel lett véve a táblába!!\n";
```

And I've checked the names of the table, and they fit perfectly.

Comment: Have you sql-escaped any of your post variables before adding them to the query? It doesn't look like it, which means your code is wide open to being hacked and having unexpected errors. Also, please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete and insecure; you are recommended to switch to using the `mysqli_xx()` functions instead, or the PDO library.

Comment: thx for the info!! i don't really know the best methods yet, casue i just started learning recently.But i'll be looking itno this:)

Comment: no worries. Read this question for more info on which functions to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php. That answer also has info and further links regarding preventing SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch the error to see what is happening:

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablanev(`OktAzonosito`,`EHAazonosito`,`TeljesNev`,`Szemelyazonosito`,`AnyaNyelv`,`VegzettsegSzint`,`AnyjaNeve`,`SzuletesiHely`,`SzuletesiEv`,`Allampolgarsag`,`Neme`,`Adoazonosito`,`TAJszam`,`BankszamlaSzam`) VALUES ('$oktazon','$ehaazon','$teljnev','$szemelyszam','$anyanyelv','$vegzettseg','$anyanev','$szulhely','$szulev','$allampolg','$neme','$taj','$bszamla')") or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set a variable like this

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablanev(`OktAzonosito`,`EHAazonosito`,`TeljesNev`,`Szemelyazonosito`,`AnyaNyelv`,`VegzettsegSzint`,`AnyjaNeve`,`SzuletesiHely`,`SzuletesiEv`,`Allampolgarsag`,`Neme`,`Adoazonosito`,`TAJszam`,`BankszamlaSzam`) VALUES ('$oktazon','$ehaazon','$teljnev','$szemelyszam','$anyanyelv','$vegzettseg','$anyanev','$szulhely','$szulev','$allampolg','$neme','$taj','$bszamla')");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

by the way, you should use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension, the use of the extension you're using is discouraged.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

edit: you miss an argument in the query the correct one is:

```
"INSERT INTO $tablanev(`OktAzonosito`,`EHAazonosito`,`TeljesNev`,`Szemelyazonosito`,`AnyaNyelv`,`VegzettsegSzint`,`AnyjaNeve`,`SzuletesiHely`,`SzuletesiEv`,`Allampolgarsag`,`Neme`,`Adoazonosito`,`TAJszam`,`BankszamlaSzam`) VALUES ('$oktazon','$ehaazon','$teljnev','$szemelyszam','$anyanyelv','$vegzettseg','$anyanev','$szulhely','$szulev','$allampolg','$neme',' $adoaz','$taj','$bszamla')"
```

Comment: It says column count doesn't match at row 1, so that means i'm trying to insert the data in the wrong orger, or i forgot something out, right?

Comment: you miss an argument, i think you have to add $adoaz to your query :)

Comment: you're welcome :) if you found useful my answers, please upvoted it and make it as accepted :)